# Verbs on second conditional

Tags: grammar

About 2nd conditionals...

> If cars **could fly**, we would commute faster.

why is the verb not in the simple past?  and, in this sentence:

> If children **got** everything they **wanted**, they wouldn't learn the value of things.

why is the verb wanted in the simple past?

Comment: The first **is** past form: *could* is the past form of *can*. And *wanted* is cast in the past form as a matter of 'tense harmony' between the main clause and its embedded relative--what's often called 'sequence of tenses'.

Comment: How can I thank this helpful answer to StoneyB? (sorry I'm new here)

Comment: You just did! You're welcome! . . . but when someone comes along who has time to give you a more thorough answer below, you may thank them by a) Upvoting the answer (click on the ▲) and, b) if it's the most useful answer you get, Accepting the answer (click on the ✔)

Comment: Looks like StoneyB answered your question, although I feel that these should have been asked as separate questions, since they are not related.  Also it would be good to add more detail explaining why you find this confusing or difficult.

Answer (score 1):

> If cars could fly, we would commute faster.

In this example, the verb "fly" is not in the past tense because the modal "could" can be used the past form of other modal "can".

So its meaning is the past tense and don't forget that you can't use a past tense verb form with "can" or "could".

> If children got everything they wanted, they wouldn't learn the value of things.

This sentence says:

> "Children want**ed** to get something and then they got it, which
>   means that there was no need to continue to want it. They had already gotten
>   what they wanted so their desire finished."

That's why "wanted" is used there.